# Не показывает результат функции в PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x

Код:

```
def say(message, times=1):
    print(message, times)

    say('hello')
    say('world', 5)

print('end')
```

выводит только:

```
end

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Поэтому не могу понять, что я делаю не так?

П.С. попробовал дальше по книге:

```
def func(a, b=5, c=10):
    print('а равно', a, 'b равно', b, 'а с равно', c)

    func(3,7)
    func(25, c=24)
    func(c=50, a=100)
print('end')
```

Результат такой же. Может старый мануал? Или должно работать ?

Comment: Отступы правильные?

Comment: да, это сюда криво скопировал (

Comment: мне кажется, дело в консоли пичарма. запустите этот же код из консоли/терминала ОС

Comment: попробовал где только мог, выводит только end, по ходу я делаю что то не так

Comment: ну хорошо, какая операционная система? какая версия пичарма?

Comment: win10, pycharm последний 2018.1.1

Comment: А можете скриншот скрипт в результат его работы в пичарме выложить в вопросе в виде скрина?

Comment: Потому что вы функцию объявили, но не вызывали. А если вы ее вызовите, то получите рекурсию. Мне кажется, что у вас урок не про рекурсии, поэтому функция func будет содержать только print.

Comment: Тогда извиняюсь, просто в книге написано создать файл внести в него те функции и ждать результат, по этому и не понял почему в итоге пусто. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Да ничего, я в ответе покажу, как я думаю должно выглядеть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def func(a, b=5, c=10):
    print('а равно',a,'b равно',b,'а с равно',c)

func(3, 7)
func(25, c=24)
func(c=50, a=100)
print('end')
```

Консоль:

```
а равно 3 b равно 7 а с равно 10
а равно 25 b равно 5 а с равно 24
а равно 100 b равно 5 а с равно 50
end
```

---

**PS.**

Я бы предложил использовать форматирование строк:

```
print(f'а равно {a}, b равно {b}, а с равно {c}')
```